# Map topic data not published on remote computer

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, ros-hydro, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm using ROS to run my own differential drive robot. Since my robot is powered by a UDOO board I'm using a minimal Ubuntu installation without GUI so I cannot run rviz on this device. For this reason I use a second laptop with ubuntu in order to control my robot. Roscore and the complete navigation stack (AMCL, move base, gmapping...) runs on the UDOO board and only rviz is running on remote laptop.

On rviz I'm able to see the laser scan, the robot pose and another topics data but I'm not able to see the map data (the topic is there and also listed by `rostopic list`).

In order to understand what is going I try to show topic data from the remote system:

```
rostopic echo scan
```

show me scan data. Instead typing

```
rostopic echo map
```

does not shown any data.
The strange thing is that the same test, performed on the system running Roscore, show me topic data for map topic too. It seems that map data only is not sent/received on the remote system!

I'm using ROS hydro and already try to update all packages on two systems and I made a succesfull network test.

Any idea about this behavior?

Thanks
Ale

UPDATE

After some tests I notice that some map topic data are published on remote PC but not every one sent by my navigation stack. Some idea about possible reason?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196445/map-topic-data-not-published-on-remote-computer/) by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2014-11-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-11-07**:
Network bandwidth? CPU/memory used out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe the message type of the /map topic is not built on the remote PC because the package containing it is not installed there!?

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) on 2014-11-02**:
Dear Wolf

I checked and map topic exist on the remote PC too.

After some test I notice that some map data are send to the remote PC but nit every data published by gmapping node. Today I will make some test using another WiFi router just to be sure the problem is not caused by bad networking.

Tha